# Explanation and printing value inside lambda function

Tags: java

I am still learning lambdas in java. I have a lambda function like this.

```
static MyClass myFunc(ClassB user) {
    return (info, cn) -> info.user.equals(user);
}
```

Now this is being called/used like this:

```
protected final MyClass myClassObject = MyClass.myFunc(userObject);
```

Where `MyClass` is an interface

I have two doubts here:

1. Since the lambda function requires `info` as well, where am I passing `info` object to it? I am definitely using it but not passing it anywhere. So, how is it using `info`
2. I want to print the value of info object inside lambda function using `System.println`. How can I do that?

Comment: @Slaw, I did it like this, ```        (info, cn) -> {return info.user.equals(user);}
``` but it complains that the return statement is missing.

Comment: You need to show a complete. runnable example.

Comment: I think you're having trouble separating the lambda expression from the instance. The `(info, cn) -> info.user.equals(user)` bit is essentially a class definition for a class that implements the `MyClass` interface. You then return an _instance_ of this class. If you understand anonymous classes, then lambda expressions are really just shorter syntax for implementing anonymous classes of functional interfaces (under the hood the two things are implemented differently, but that doesn't matter to you).